# How do I fix the audio on my laptop. model Fujitsu B6220

Tags: sound, intel

I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop because the Unity desktop was freezing.

Reinstalling 12.04 seems to have fixed the freezing problem, but now the audio does not work.  When I go to **Settings > Audio**, under the **Output** tab it only has the option for Digital Output.  There is no option for Analog Output.

The sound card shows up under lspci as:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
```

What would be the command to reinstall the audio subsystem?  If that would fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fixed the problem in my case:

Enter in terminal the command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Add to the bottom of the file:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

Reboot the computer

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and issue these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils libasound2
sudo apt-get -y install gdm ubuntu-desktop linux-image-`uname -r`
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install libasound2 linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall lightdm ubuntu-desktop linux-image-$(uname -r)
killall pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.pulse*
sudo usermod -aG $(cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g') $USER
```

When you finish, restart your system. If sound still missing from your system, you can check this [article](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/06/how-to-fix-no-sound-problems-on-ubuntu.html)

Comment: I tried all the commands above and they didn't work, so I looked at the article you linked to and The last thing on the list worked!!  Under "Onboard Realtek ALC887"

sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

add at the bottom of the file opened with the above command:
options snd-hda-intel model=generic


I reinstalled Ubuntu again to recreate the same problem and I only did the above and that alone fixed it!